# Got 403 while sending FCM from flutter app with logged in user other then firebase account owner

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-403

I can send/receive FCM (v1) to topic from my flutter app when I authenticated (SignedIn to my Google account - Firebase project owner), so I can get access token to add authentication (bearer) to send request.
Problem: error 403 during send FCM, when somebody else is using my app and SignedIn with his credentials. But he receives FCM without problems.
Thanks in advance,
David.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough to answer. Please add some code snippets and a bit more details.

Answer (score 0):

(HTTP error code = 403) The authenticated sender ID is different from the sender ID for the registration token.

A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for FCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.